# React Native Looping Animation Performance

Tags: react-native, performance, animation

I have a react native app and I want to have a fireworks animation playing on loop more or less indefinitely. I have implemented an animation I am happy with using the built-in react native animated library, however the performance monitor shows the UI thread down at 30 fps (and I can feel my iPhone heating up after about 10 seconds too). I can bring it back up to 60 fps by reducing the number of firework bursts or stars, but I would like to keep the amount I have if possible because it looks nicer. Are there any optimizations you see I can do to get it back to 60 fps without compromising the look of the fireworks?

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import { View, Animated, Easing, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", backgroundColor: "black" }}>
      <Fireworks />
    </View>
  );
}

const random = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;

const NUM_BURSTS = 10;
const STAR_SIZE_MIN = 2;
const STAR_SIZE_MAX = 6;
const NUM_STARS = 200;
const NUM_OUTER_STARS = NUM_STARS / 2;
const DURATION_MIN = 1000;
const DURATION_MAX = 3000;
const BURST_SPEED = 7;
const RADIUS_MIN = 30;
const RADIUS_MAX = 100;

const Fireworks = () => {
  const [bursts, setBursts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    //Create all the firework bursts one time at component mount.
    const newBursts = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < NUM_BURSTS; i++) {
      const starSize = random(STAR_SIZE_MIN, STAR_SIZE_MAX);
      newBursts.push({
        starSize
      });
    }
    setBursts(newBursts);
  }, []);

  const renderBursts = bursts?.map((burst, index) =>
    <FireworkBurst starSize={burst.starSize} key={"" + index} />
  );

  return (
    <View style={{ position: "absolute", top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0 }}>
      {renderBursts}
    </View>
  )
}

const FireworkBurst = ({ starSize }) => {
  const viewRef = useRef();
  const animValue = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const [stars, setStars] = useState([]);
  const loop = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const radius = random(RADIUS_MIN, RADIUS_MAX);
    const newStars = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < NUM_STARS; i++) {
      const star = generateStar(i, radius);
      newStars.push(star);
    }
    setStars(newStars);

    loop.current = true;
    animate();

    return () => {
      loop.current = false;
    }
  }, []);

  const generateStar = (iteration, radius) => {
    const star = {
      starSize
    };
    const end = {}
    if (iteration < NUM_OUTER_STARS) {
      const value = iteration / NUM_OUTER_STARS;
      end.x = Math.sin(value * Math.PI * 2) * radius;
      end.x += random(-10, 10);
      end.y = -Math.cos(value * Math.PI * 2) * radius;
      end.y += random(-10, 10);
    }
    else {
      end.x = random(-(radius - 10), radius - 10);
      end.y = random(-(radius - 10), radius - 10);
    }
    star.end = end;
    return star;
  }

  const animate = useCallback(() => {
    const x = random(0, 100);
    const y = random(0, 100);
    //set native props to avoid re-rendering
    viewRef?.current?.setNativeProps({ top: `${y}%`, left: `${x}%` });

    animValue.setValue(0);
    Animated.timing(
      animValue,
      {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: random(DURATION_MIN, DURATION_MAX),
        easing: Easing.out(Easing.poly(BURST_SPEED)),
        isInteraction: false,
        useNativeDriver: true
      }
    ).start(() => {
      loop.current && animate();
    });
  }, [animValue]);

  const renderStars = stars.map((star, index) =>
    <FireworkStar starSize={star.starSize} end={star.end} animValue={animValue} key={"" + index} />
  );

  return (
    <Animated.View ref={viewRef} style={{ position: "absolute" }}>
      {renderStars}
    </Animated.View>
  )
}

const FireworkStar = ({ starSize, end, animValue }) => {

  const translateX = animValue.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [0, end.x]
  })

  const translateY = animValue.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [0, end.y]
  })

  const opacity = animValue.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 0.9, 1],
    outputRange: [1, 1, 0]
  });

  const hue = random(0, 255);
  const color = `hsl(${hue},100%,70%)`;

  return (
    <Animated.View
      style={{
        position: "absolute", top: 0, left: 0,
        height: starSize, width: starSize, borderRadius: starSize,
        justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: color,
        transform: [
          { translateX },
          { translateY }
        ]
      }}
      opacity={opacity}
    >
    </Animated.View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using `Animated.loop`?

Comment: Yes, I started with using loop() but then realized I couldn't run any code in between each iteration. I need to change the position of the viewRef for the firework burst  each time it loops and there's no way (that I know of) to do that when using loop().